# How to get the max value of list that have value in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I have two lists

1. task=[1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5]
2. hours=[1,7,6,2,3,6,5,2,4,6]
3. 

-.I want to ask the user input a number between 1 to 5 and then look the user's input to similler values in list task (if user's input 1 then I need to print the max of first four index in hours list (because number 1 have 4 index in list task) ) So the output will be "Task number (input) can be completed in (max of first four index in hours) hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to loop over the pairs, and you take maximum of the task-hours where the task number matches what was input.

```
task = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5]
hours = [1,7,6,2,3,6,5,2,4,6]

num = int(input('Which task number?'))

print(max(h for n,h in zip(task, hours) if n == num))
```

Comment: This is a fine solution if the process needs to be applied only once. For more than one task to process, you waste efficiency by having to read the whole thing again.

Comment: @mozway True. If the lists are large enough to care about this, then one could set up a dictionary. I would probably be inclined to make a dictionary just containing the maximum length for each task number. (It would also be possible to create a dictionary containing a list of individual items for each task number, and calculate the maximum of these when required, but that might require rather more memory depending on the average number of tasks per task number.)

Comment: @mozway Essentially `mydict = defaultdict(int)` and then just loop over doing `for n,h in zip(task, hours): mydict[n] = max(mydict[n], h)`

Comment: [I know](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70141203/16343464) :p

Answer (score 0):

Use a different type of container, a dictionary is more appropriate. Here is how to convert from your format:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in zip(task,hours):
    d[k].append(v)
```

output:

```
>>> dict(d)
{1: [1, 7, 6, 2], 2: [3, 6], 3: [5], 4: [2], 5: [4, 6]}
```

Then you can just select the task and get the max:

```
n = 1
max(d[n])
```

output: `7`

Answer (score -1):

```
n = int(input("Pick a valid number between 1 and 5: "))
result = max(hours[:len(task) - 1 - task.index(n)])
print("Task number {0} can be completed in {1} hours".format(n, result))
```

All this is doing is getting the user's input, then finding the last index of the number in `task`, then getting the max of the first *n* elements from `hours`. Finally, it prints the formatted results.

Comment: this is not correct, try with n=5